# Not able to invoke the WCF function

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, wcf-binding

I've an asp .net application, my Data Access Layer is a WCF service. I use VWD Express 2010. The whole structure in a bird's eye view is something like this

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IExcelReader
    {
       [OperationContract]
       [FaultContract(typeof(StaffAllocationFault))]        
       void ReadExcel();
    }
```

```
    public void ReadExcel()
    {
        DataSet dataCollection = new DataSet();

        table = new DataTable("Capacity");

        //gets the connection string for the excelsheet with the employee details
        //string strCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["capacityDB"].ConnectionString;
        string strCon = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\CapacityDB.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0";

        //gets the predefined filters in the application
        string[] filter = GetDefinedFilters();

        //creates the connection object
        oledbCon = new OleDbConnection(strCon);

        try
        {
            //opens the connection object
            openConnection();

            string strCmd = "Select * from [Capacity Report Data$]";

            //creates the command object
            oledbCmd = new OleDbCommand(strCmd, oledbCon);

            //fills the datatable using the data adapter
            oledbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            oledbAdapter.SelectCommand = oledbCmd;
            oledbAdapter.Fill(table);

            dataCollection.Tables.Add(table);

            //to trim off the trailing/preceding whitespaces
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                int count = 0;

                while (count < filter.Count())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        row[filter[count]] = row[filter[count]].ToString().Trim();

                        //if the field is blank
                        if (row[filter[count]].ToString() == "")
                            row[filter[count]] = "***";

                        count++;
                    }

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new FaultException<StaffAllocationFault>(new StaffAllocationFault { FaultMessage = "Error while reading through the employee information" }, ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }                
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new FaultException<StaffAllocationFault>(new StaffAllocationFault { FaultMessage = "Error while retreiving employee information" }, ex.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            //closes the oledb connection
            closeConnection();
        }
    }
```

```
    public void ReadFromExcel()
    {
        try
        {
            new ExcelReaderClient().ReadExcel();
        }
        //service specific exceptions
        catch (FaultException<StaffAllocationFault> ex)
        {
            throw new ExceptionLayer.StaffAllocationException("Error while reading from excel", ex);
        }
        //generic exceptions
        catch (Exception genEx)
        {
            throw genEx;
        }
    }
```

My `web.config` in UI:

```
<client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:49171/ExcelReader.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IExcelReader" contract="ExcelService.IExcelReader"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_IExcelReader" />
    </client>
```

when I run the application the function in the wcf is not getting invoked. Pls help.

Comment: nopes... i didn't get any errors ;(

Comment: What have you configured in your web.config? WCF needs to have its endpoints specified.

Comment: i've this in my web .config in UI.., <endpoint address="http://localhost:49171/Simple.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISimple" contract="SimpleService.ISimple"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_ISimple" />

Comment: The suggestion that the method isn't being called *and* you're not getting any errors seems highly unlikely. Have you stepped through the code with the debugger? If so, what happens when you reach the `new SimpleClient().Sample()` line and step into it? It might be worth posting the real code, because if there's more to it than you've posted here, it's quite possible that you've missed something.

Comment: I find the best way to diagnose this sort of stuff is with WCF tracing.  See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Comment: ya i used step into... It just goes to the next line in the business layer... and does not go into the function in the service layer...

Comment: wcf is not getting invoked when the application runs. so wcf tracing could not be done..

Comment: AH - either check the Output window or enable reporting of all exceptions - visual Studio will not inform you about many exceptions by default. Go to Debug --> Exceptions... then tick Thrown for Common language runtime Exceptions and click OK. Run your code again and see if it throws an exception now.

Answer (score 0):

Create a virtual directory for the WCF service in IIS from the Visual studio. After that invoke the WcfTestClient from the VS command prompt, and try to add the wcf service reference to the WCFTestClient (the url in ur case might be something like http://localhost/VirtualDirectoryName/ExcelReader.svc) - If the Service and its methods are accessible you can test it from tool - otherwise it will give you appropriate errors